# Algorithm to partition sum between buckets in all unique ways

Tags: algorithms, integer-partitions

### The Problem

I need an algorithm that does this:

> Find all the unique ways to partition a given sum across 'buckets' not caring about order

I hope I was <del>clear</del> reasonably coherent in expressing myself. <del>I didn't put in code as the algorithm isn't fleshed out yet</del> Done.

### Example

For the sum 5 and 3 buckets, what the algorithm should return is:

> [5, 0, 0]
>   [4, 1, 0]
>   [3, 2, 0]
>   [3, 1, 1]
>   [2, 2, 1]

### Disclaimer

I'm sorry if this question might be a dupe, but I don't know exactly what these sort of problems are called. Still, I searched on Google and Math.SE using all wordings that I could think of, but only found results for distributing in the most *even* way, not all unique ways.

### Solution

OK, so I tinkered around a bit and came up with a solution. Since I didn't want to rob the awesome guys here who were faster than me of their rep, I'm not accepting my own answer, but putting it here. It's in Python which is practically like pseudocode with a compiler.

My first attempt worked, but it was horribly inefficient:

```
def intPart(buckets, balls):
    return uniqify(_intPart(buckets, balls))

def _intPart(buckets, balls):
    solutions = []

    # base case
    if buckets == 1:
        return [[balls]]

    # recursive strategy
    for i in range(balls + 1):
        for sol in _intPart(buckets - 1, balls - i):
            cur = [i]
            cur.extend(sol)
            solutions.append(cur)

    return solutions

def uniqify(seq):
    seen = set()
    sort = [list(reversed(sorted(elem))) for elem in seq]
    return [elem for elem in sort if str(elem) not in seen and not seen.add(str(elem))]
```

Here's my reworked solution. It completely avoids the need to 'uniquify' it by the tracking the balls in the previous bucket using the `max_` variable. This sorts the lists and prevents any dupes.

```
def intPart(buckets, balls, max_ = None):
    # init vars
    sols = []
    if max_ is None:
        max_ = balls
    min_ = max(0, balls - max_)

    # assert stuff
    assert buckets >= 1
    assert balls >= 0

    # base cases
    if (buckets == 1):
        if balls <= max_:
            sols.append([balls])
    elif balls == 0:
        sol = [0] * buckets
        sols.append(sol)

    # recursive strategy
    else:
        for there in range(min_, balls + 1):
            here = balls - there
            ways = intPart(buckets - 1, there, here)
            for way in ways:
                sol = [here]
                sol.extend(way)
                sols.append(sol)

    return sols
```

Comment: Number of partitions into a given number of parts. Probably still a duplicate, but not of the question currently linked. Voting to reopen (but hope someone has a look to see if it's a real duplicate of some other question).

Answer (score 2):

This is Perl, but the algorithm is straightforward and should be easy to implement in any language:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl

      sub part {
        my ($n, $b, $min) = @_;
        $min = 0 unless defined $min;

        # base case
        if ($b == 0) {
          if ($n == 0) { return ( [] ) }
          else         { return ()     }
        }

        my @partitions;
        for my $first ($min .. $n) {
          my @sub_partitions = part($n - $first, $b-1, $first);
          for my $sp (@sub_partitions) {
            push @partitions, [$first, @$sp];
          }
        }
        return @partitions;
      }
```

The function `part` gets two arguments: $n$ is the total number of beans that you want (5 in your example) and $b$ is the number of buckets (3 in your example).  It also gets an auxiliary argument, $min$, which is the smallest permissible bucket value.  This defaults to 0 if it is not supplied.

The function is recursive, just as you suggested. The base case is no buckets, $b=0$.  If there are no beans to put into the buckets ($n=0$ also) then this can be satisfied in exactly one way, by an empty array of buckets `[]`.  Otherwise there is no solution because there are beans left over but no buckets to put them in.

If $b>0$ then the function will accumulate a list of possible partitions of $n$ beans into $b$ buckets in the array `@partitions`.  It will do this by selecting the number of beans to go into the first bucket ($first$), recursively allocating the remaining beans into $b-1$ buckets, and assembling the two into a complete solution, which it will append to `@partitions`. This is just what you suggested in your question.

The number of the beans in the first bucket must be at least $min$, and at most $n$, the total number of beans.

The function then calls itself recursively: there are $n-first$ beans to allocate to $b-1$ buckets, but no bucket can have fewer than $first$ beans.  This last bit is the only tricky part: it ensures that the number of beans never decreases from each bucket to the next, and so that each generated partition is unique.  (Without this restriction, `[1,2,2]`, `[2,1,2]`, and `[2,2,1]` would be different solutions.  With this restriction, only `[1,2,2]` is generated.)

The recursive call returns a number of partitions of $n-first$ beans into $b-1$ buckets.   $first$ is appended to each of these (that's `[$first, @$sp]`, which makes a single array out of `$first` and the contents of `$sp`) and the resulting partitions of $n$ beans into $b$  buckets are pushed onto `@partitions`.  When this has been  done for each permissible value of $first$, the complete `@partitions` list is returned.

To test  your example, I did:

```
    for my $p ( part(5, 3) ) {
      print "@$p\n";
    }
```

Which printed:

```
0 0 5
0 1 4
0 2 3
1 1 3
1 2 2
```

To get the partitions with largest element first, just change `[$first, @$sp]` to `[@$sp, $first]`.

Some minor optimization are possible.  For example, if $n < b\cdot min$ then one can halt the recursion immediately, returning no solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This was exactly the kind fo answer I was looking for. Just one thing: any more readable language? Pseudocode or Python would do. I simply can't understand Perl w/o learning it first...

Comment: Why not just pretend that the Perl is pseudocode?

Comment: OK, just save me 3 Google searches: 1) What does the `push` and `my` keywords do? 2) What does the `@` symbol mean? 3) How do for loops in Perl work?

Comment: `@` marks an array variable; `$` marks a scalar variable.  `my` declares a variable that is private to the block it is in.  `for my $var (LIST) { ... } ` iterates the code in curly braces once for each element of *LIST*, with the  variable `$var` set to each element of the list in turn.  `$min .. $n` generates a list of integers starting from `$min` and going up to `$n`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to program this by hand is probably a recursive approach.  Define a function

```
Part(n, m, max)
```

which will distribute `n` items between `m` boxes, putting at most `max` in each box.  The code for `Part` splits into two cases.  If `m = 1` then return an empty list if `n > max` and return `[[n]]` otherwise.  If `m > 1` then for each $0 \leq i \leq n$ prepend `i` onto the beginning of the results from `Part(n - i, m - 1, i)` and return the whole collection.

The answer you want is given by `Part(n, m, n)`.

Comment: It doesn't result in unique solutions. Of course, you _could_ do later filtering, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: The function needs the additional $min$ argument that my solution has. It can use this to force the parts of each partition to appear in increasing order, which forces the solutions to be unique.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  I missed the part about order not mattering.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I want to comment on the Perl answer but I don't have enough points.
Here is the same answer in Python:

```
def partition(n, b, minimum=0):
    if b == 1:
        if n == 0:
            return [[]]
        else:
            return [[n]]

    partitions = []
    for i in range(minimum, n):
        sub_partitions = partition(n - i, b - 1, i)
        for sub_partition in sub_partitions:
            partitions.append([i] + sub_partition)
    return partitions
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica:

```
IntegerPartitions[5, 3]
```

Comment: Can you give the output of what will that return? Exactly as described in the question? If so, could you like give an idea of how this function works?

Comment: {{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}

Comment: The basic idea of how it works is exactly what MJD posted. However, Wolfram has some clever Mathematicians writing these functions, so I would bet they have come up with some clever optimizations, and you would be well-suited to not redo the work they have already done.

Comment: I consider myself a clever mathematician as well.

Comment: Of course I'm not implying you're not. But I would be willing to bet that you didn't spend 13 years developing and optimizing that code you just posted ;)

Comment: Anyway, this answer is nonresponsive.  The question asks for an algorithm to generate permutations. "Get Mathematica to do it" is not an algorithm.

Comment: @Amzoti Mathematica returns it as a list. My first comment was copy-pasted Mathematica output.